# Replace function with variables in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have written this procedure in oracle which is using replace function. I have used variables instead of directly passing string in it, but that is not working. It is not replacing the string.
Please find below my piece of code :

```
l_course_alias_query := 'select course_name, alias from ZMAR_TRANS.ZMAR_COURSE_ALIAS';

OPEN l_cur_alias_list FOR l_course_alias_query;

LOOP


  FETCH l_cur_alias_list into l_trng_name,l_alias_name;

  EXIT WHEN l_cur_alias_list%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_trng_name);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_alias_name);

  l_query := replace(l_query,l_trng_name,l_alias_name);

end LOOP;
CLOSE l_cur_alias_list;
```

Comment: I am sure that `replace` *is* working correctly, but that you either have a wrong expectation of `replace` or that the data is not what you think it is. Without further details from your side, we cannot possible give you an answer.

Comment: Variable `l_query` seems to be `NULL` before replace. There is no code to initialize it.

Comment: I suggest you `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);` before and after the `replace`.